# Limit the maximum number of results in ActiveRecord + Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, activerecord, kaminari

When using Rails and Kaminari, is it possible to limit the maximum number of results to be returned for a given query?

```
@things = Thing.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Assuming we have 500k+ `Thing` records in the database, how can I ensure that Kaminari's `paginate` method will never return more than 10,000 rows to paginate?

Answer (score 1):

Kaminari has a [`max_per_page` option](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#general-configuration-options) that may be helpful, but it may work via the limit scope method also offered here.

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out a way to do that using an initializer for Kaminari in `config/initializers/kaminari_config.rb`:

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.default_per_page = 10
  config.max_per_page = 100
  config.max_pages = 100
end
```

In the above case, 100 * 100 = 10,000 maximum total results

More info [here](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#general-configuration-options)

Answer (score 1):

`max_per_page` actually sets settings globally. To have individual resource based settings, **Kaminari** supports `Array` type objects as well. So, something like below works perfect:

```
limited_newsfeeds = Newsfeed.order(:created_at).limit(20)

@newfeeds = Kaminari.paginate_array(limited_newsfeed).page(params[:page]).per(3)
```

You may easily use this `@newsfeed` object same like normal collection in kaminari views, like

```
<%= paginate @newsfeeds, remote: true %>
```

**TIP**: Using `limit()` method directly before/after `page()` doesn't serve the purpose. It either overwrites kaminari's limit (when used **after** `page()` method), or gets replaced-by kaminari's limit (when used **before** `page()` method)

Source: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object

Answer (score 0):

So you're interested in just the top 10k rows? This should do it, but I would consider adding some sorting criteria in there (before the call to `limit`) so that your chosen 10000 rows make sense.

```
Thing.limit(10000).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Comment: `per` will actually override any `limit` set before it.